# Python - Assign None or value

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a short way to assign None or value in a variable, depending on the value?

```
x= value if value!= 999 else None
```

Comment: I think this is very readable way of accomplishing what you're trying to do. No need to make it shorter except if you're code golfing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> result = (on_false, on_true)[condition]

```
>>> value = 10
>>> x = (None,value)[value != 999]
>>> print x
10

>>> value = 999
>>> x = (None,value)[value != 999]
>>> print x
None
```

Comment: I personally find the OP's method to be more readable, though. Citing the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2): "Readability counts."

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct way to do it.

but if you insist on shorten way to figure it out you can use this method:

**first way:**

```
{0:value}.get(value==999)
```

using the trick python saving same hash for False and 0 (hash = 0).

**second way:**

```
{999:None}.get(value,value)
```

using get method and default value to bring this.

**third way:**

```
[None, value][value != 999]
```

when first part stand for value declaration and the second as boolean condition.

Comment: Whilst possibly correct, I would argue that all of these are far more obscure than OP's original code.

Comment: I have to agree with you :) OP asked for a "short way", so trying to help with my code golf skills :)